# How to add order by into statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

Does anybody know how to insert order by into the statement below

```
SELECT ctr_num,
       scn
FROM   user_convoy
WHERE  ctr_num LIKE '%" + str_convoy + "%'"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really sure about your question, but from my understanding, it should be:

```
select ctr_num , scn from user_convoy where ctr_num like '%" + str_convoy + "%'" ORDER BY your_column
```

Answer (score 1):

Add ORDER BY at the end. The general format of your SELECT statements is generally SELECT FROM WHERE ORDER BY (assuming no grouping, of course).  Note that it is not case-sensitive.

```
select ctr_num , scn from user_convoy where ctr_num like '%' + str_convoy + '%' ORDER BY ctr_num
```

Answer (score 1):

*The ORDER BY keyword is used to sort the result-set by one or more columns.*

Try below if you want to use Order By.

```
SELECT ctr_num,
       scn
FROM   user_convoy
WHERE  ctr_num LIKE '%' + str_convoy + '%'
ORDER BY
       ctr_num,scn
```

For more details:

Please refer [**w3schools Example**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) and to learn in more depth **[this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188723(v=sql.105).aspx)**